# Decrypting .png images from the asset

Tags: encryption, png, assets

I am a student who has recently started to learn Java and Android development.

I was trying to see the structure and extract assets from the discontinued mobile game for learning purposes. While being successful at decompiling `.apk` and extracting assets from `.obb`, I have noticed that image files in the assets were encrypted. In hex view, files lacked a header and had no distinctive features such as repeating bytes.

With a former success of decrypting ".png" files in the assets from the other game encrypted with XOR encryption, I have tried the brute method of XOR decrypting but miserably failed.

Now I think that my (shallow) approach is wrong and these files might have another type of encryption other than XOR, but unfortunately, I have very little understanding of file encryptions and I am stuck. Therefore I would be genuinely grateful if anybody could provide a hint on how to approach decrypting these files.

**Attachment**: [4 Example files(Google drive link)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U42rKF9-Oq7qIQR6uF695HT-9BmYwIe4?usp=sharing)

Comment: A question with code kept at another website might be interesting for current users but it will be useless for future users as soon as the links go dead. That's why questions need to be self-contained: your code needs to be right in the body of the question. Also, you should probably be aware that there is a stack exchange site devoted to reverse engineering: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I will be careful next time and I shall also check the StackExchange site.